# Retrieving information from solrj in JSF

Tags: mysql, jsf, solr

Update: Simplified example and changed my question.
With the following code when the keyword is found it retrieves data but when I use a keyword which is not in the data it gives me `org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: missing content stream`

```
class SearchBean
{
    public void query(String q) throws IOException
    {
        HttpSolrServer server = null;

        try
        {
            server = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8080/solr/");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
        query.setQuery(q); 
        query.setFacet(true);
        query.addFacetField("name");
        query.addFacetField("title");        
        try
        {
            QueryResponse rsp = server.query(query);

            SolrDocumentList docs = rsp.getResults();
            List<ExampleBean> beans = rsp.getBeans(ExampleBean.class);
            server.addBeans(beans);            

            System.out.println("Found: " + docs.getNumFound());
            System.out.println("Start: " + docs.getStart());
            System.out.println("Max Score: " + docs.getMaxScore());
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            System.out.println(rsp.toString());  
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            for(ExampleBean example:beans){
                System.out.println(example.getName().toString());
            }
        }
        catch (SolrServerException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
        SearchBean solrj = new SearchBean();
        solrj.query("test");
    }
}
```

I have indexed my data and imported to solr via data-config.xml

Comment: Are you unsure how to use SolrJ, or is this specifically a JSF question? Are you trying to make a search page like the admin query page?

Comment: I added some code and explanation, I hope I've clarified my question. Please let me know if I need to specify more details about my question.

Comment: Your code is hard to follow. These tips may help, but they might just correct typos: the index.xhtml file has a missing '{' at `action=#example..`. The action expression doesn't match the controller method (the controller method takes no arguments). The controller also sets the keyword="", so it would seem you are carrying out an empty search.

Comment: The missing bracket is only a copy-pase mistake. My approach is to instantiate solr server in AbstractFacade so that I reuse it in all my beans. Then I query solr in the beanFacade, and construct a search method in the beanController. I need to take end-user's keyword to search, how do I define the search method and the keyword?

Comment: The keyword will already be sent to be back bean by the `<inputText />`. I suggest you make a very simple test set up first (just 1 XHTML file and 1 back bean). That way you can isolate the problem.

Comment: @Mowgli I did as you advised and ran into another issue which I have specified in my question.

Comment: I don't see the point of the line: `server.addBeans(beans)`. That may throw an exception if the returned results list is empty.

Comment: Don't I need to add my brans to solr server using this line?